# How to use the GAPI Client Library (Google Sign-In for Web) for existing apps after March 31, 2023 for the example given?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-javascript-client

The GAPI Client Library (Google Sign-In for Web) is being deprecated after March 31, 2023, but:

> existing  client IDs created before July 29th, 2022 may set the `plugin_name` to enable use of the legacy Google platform library.

See: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

Before March 31, 2023, an existing page (given below) will print the `googleUser` object to console after a successful Google Sign-In:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta
        name="google-signin-client_id"
        content="*****************.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      />
      <meta
        name="google-signin-scope"
        content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"
      />
    <title>Google Login Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `init()` on success. -->
      <p class="g-signin2 mt-4 mb-4 screen-only" data-onsuccess="init"></p>

      <script>
      function init(googleUser) {
        console.log(googleUser);
      }
      </script>

      <!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library. -->
      <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

The [documentation suggests](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig) that adding `plugin_name` as part of the `gapi.auth2.ClientConfig` object will allow an existing integration to work for a while longer.

The sample above does not have a `gapi.auth2.ClientConfig` specified, but does have meta tags for `client_id` and `scope` (which are parameters for `gapi.auth2.ClientConfig`).

**To get this example working after March 31, 2023, do I just add a meta tag in this format?**

```
<meta name="google-signin-CLIENT_CONFIG_PARAMETER_NAME" content="CLIENT_CONFIG_PARAMETER_VALUE" />
```

**Like so?**

```
<meta name="google-signin-plugin_name" content="My App Name Here" />
```

Comment: Were you able to make this work?

Comment: Well, it still works when I added the extra meta tags, so isnt any worse. I guess we'll find out on April 1, 2023 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now we're after March 31, 2023, I can answer this.

The method described above, adding...

```
<meta name="google-signin-plugin_name" content="My App Name Here" />
```

..does appear to work just fine.

Just replace `My App Name Here` with something more descriptive for your app.